# In CentOS 7, is there a way to specify which block devices should be tuned with the scheduler (or ELEVATOR)?

Tags: linux, grub2, block, block-device, scheduler

In CentOS 6, there was `/etc/tune-profiles/my-server/ktune.sysconfig` with this text(I'm referring to the comments that explain what the code is doing):

```
# This is the I/O scheduler ktune will use.  This will *not* override anything
# explicitly set on the kernel command line, nor will it change the scheduler
# for any block device that is using a non-default scheduler when ktune starts.
# You should probably leave this on "deadline", but "as", "cfq", and "noop" are
# also legal values.  Comment this out to prevent ktune from changing I/O
# scheduler settings.
ELEVATOR="deadline"

# These are the devices, that should be tuned with the ELEVATOR
ELEVATOR_TUNE_DEVS="/sys/block/{sd,cciss,vd,dasd,xvd}*/queue/scheduler"
```

But it seems like CentOS 7 has left `ktune` behind. I see an alternate [method](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/performance_tuning_guide/sect-red_hat_enterprise_linux-performance_tuning_guide-storage_and_file_systems-configuration_tools) to change the default I/O scheduler:

> Add the *`elevator`* parameter to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` line in the `/etc/default/grub` file.

```
# cat /etc/default/grub
...
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=vg00/lvroot rd.lvm.lv=vg00/lvswap elevator=noop"
...
```

And it goes on. But this would be a system-wide change. I'm looking for a solution like I had in CentOS 6 where I could specify which block devices would get the I/O scheduler specified by the `ELEVATOR` parameter. I was hoping I could just add the `elevator_tune_devs` parameter to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` line, but according to [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html), there is no such kernel parameter. I know I can do this:

```
echo 'noop' > /sys/block/hda/queue/scheduler
```

for example, but I was hoping for something that lasts past the reboot. The best solution so far is to stick that `echo` command in a one-shot service so it'd be run every time at boot, but I was hoping for a cleaner method similar to the CentOS 6 solution.

Comment: Put the commands in /etc/rc.d/rc.local, it'll last past the reboot.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant as a one-shot service (``systemd`` executes ``/etc/rc.d/rc.local`` as part of the service ``rc-local``), but I was looking for a cleaner method, like I said at the end. Thanks, though

Comment: I guess we have very different ideas of what clean means.  Adding another piece of software where it's unnecessary for something so simple as this would not be my choice.

Comment: Honestly, I'm a newb. I just got my perception of `rc.local` from the answers here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471824/what-is-the-correct-substitute-for-rc-local-in-systemd-instead-of-re-creating-rc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have at least two methods:

- use a custom tuned profile with the [right `disk` option](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/performance_tuning_guide/chap-red_hat_enterprise_linux-performance_tuning_guide-tuned)
- insert the "echo noop" command in `/etc/rc.local` or create a specific systemd service.

**EDIT:** here you can find an example `tuned.conf` file:

```
# tuned configuration

[main]
summary=ZFS General non-specialized tuned profile
include=balanced

[disk]
# Comma separated list of devices, all devices if commented out.
type=disk
devices=sda,sdb
elevator=noop
```

As described in the RHEL tuned guide I linked above you have different possibilities to define the device list:

- via coma separated list (as per example above);
- via wildcards (eg: `sd*`);
- to *all* disks, by not specifying anything (as by the comment included in the file above).

Comment: hmm,  Are you saying that putting
``[disk]``
``devices=sd*, cciss*, vd*, dasd*, xvd*``
in ``/etc/tuned/my-profile/tuned.conf`` (for example) would make the ``elevator`` parameter in the ``GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`` line in ``/etc/default/grub`` only apply to the disks in ``devices``?

Comment: To be clear, I'm asking for clarification on the first method you listed, please. I can't test it right now, but please provide and example of what to do if what I commented is not what you were suggesting.

Comment: Yes you can optionally filter devices in the `[disk]` section of a tuned profile.  But the `elevator` you set there is inserted into sysfs by tuned. grub isn't involved.

Comment: @LeviUzodike I updated my answer with a practical example